# How to reverse content between tag with JQuery?

Tags: jquery

For example, I have:

```
<span class="a">abcdef</span>
<span class="b">123456</span>
<span class="b">abc<span class="c">def</span>ghi</span>
```

And want to reverse only the text between `<span class="b">` like this

```
<span class="a">abcdef</span>
654321
ihg<span class="c">def</span>cba
```

How to do it with JQuery?

Comment: Do you really want to unwrap the span as well? The reversal itself is quite easy if you know said span contains only text and no tags.

Comment: Yes, I want to unwrap the span as well.
I've just edited the question to make it clear.

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve? Are you trying to replicate some kind of right-to-left functionality that browsers normally have?

Comment: No. Just some texts with that span in a code.

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do can be described as:

- Reverse the order child nodes of each `span.b`.
- Reverse the text in each text child node of each.
- Finally, replace each with its content.

jQuery doesn't have a `reverse` method, but it has a `get` method that can convert the jQuery object into an array, and arrays do have a `reverse` method. Then we put the elements back.

jQuery cannot manipulate text node content (and the text content of their parent elements is not good enough for our purposes), but the respective native DOM interface is well standardised, so we can use that. Unfortunately, strings don't have a reverse method as of ES5. Fortunately, we can convert them to an array.

[`unwrap`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) seems like a useful method here, but the documentation does not imply it would work for non-element nodes. Also, we want to remove the `span` even if it is empty. `unwrap` does not achieve that. Instead, we can use [`replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/).

Further optimisations: since we're discarding the span anyways, we don't need to actually reverse its children within the span. `replaceWith` accepts a function as an argument. We can use that to minimise the number of calls to `replaceWith`. Also, we would like to avoid `$(this).contents().get()` because that involves creation of two extra jQuery elements per iteration. Instead, we can make use of the array-like `childNodes` that holds the same. While this array-like doesn't have a `reverse` method of its own, the one that arrays have will work here, too.

This should do the job:

```
$("span.b").replaceWith(function(){
  var children = this.childNodes;
  for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++){
    if(children[i].nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE){
       children[i].nodeValue = children[i].nodeValue.split("").reverse().join("");
    }
  }
  return [].reverse.call(children)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this might help:

```
var span$ = $( '.b' ),
    txt = span$.text();
span$.prev().after( txt );
span$.remove();
```

There's also `unwrap` function ih JQuery http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/

Comment: This doesn't achieve the effect of reversing the contents